# Capacitive soil moisture sensor and differential switch

Tags: sensor, humidity, soil-sensing

While using a [capacitive moisture sensor](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1385.html) I experience this weird behavior: when I insert the moisture sensor into the ground, the line differential switch breaks. Thus, I need to disconnect both the 5 VDC wire as well as the data.

Why is this happening? It didn't happen when I was prototyping (powering the probe through a Wemos D1 mini). But as soon as put "into production", I started experiencing this. Something worth mentioning is that the probe started giving trouble when first inserted into the ground. It didn't happen when it was out of the soil, surrounded by just air.

### Schematics for the microcontroller board

https://tinypic.host/i/huerta-bb.MWIMR

### Actual picture of the PSU and how it provides 5Vdc to the sensors

https://tinypic.host/i/psu.MdunQ

Comment: Seems like power supply is not grounded, isn't it? Possible low quality power supply with high capacitance or current leak between input and output parts. Provide circuit and PSU model please.

Comment: "the line differential switch"  what?

Comment: Murphy's Law strikes again. Sounds like a lack of testing before production.

Comment: are you saying that you did not insert the probe into the ground when you were prototyping the device?

Comment: @Jasen sorry man, not sure how is that device called in English. I know it's no the best translation but basically, it detects a leak between mains and ground and breaks the (turns off?) the line power (mains). Does that make more sense?

Comment: @jsotola I didn't. I just used a glass of water to calibrate analog readings.

Comment: @Vladimir right, it is not grounded. It is a regular 5v 2A PSU. I reused this PSU from another device.

Comment: This is what I meant by "differential switch": https://www.ledkia.com/blog/uk/what-is-a-circuit-breaker-and-how-does-it-work/#differential-circuit-breaker

Comment: In North America, your "differential, switch" is known as a Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter", or GFCI.  In other courtries it may be called an RCD, I think.

Comment: We need more information on the PSU. Is it isolated? It sounds like when you insert the sensor into the [literal, earth] ground some current is flowing which is precisely what a GFCI/RCD/"Line Differential Switch" is designed to protect against. What is "mains" in your region? Also, just want to mention that your picture is setting off all sorts of safety alarm bells in my head; mains current that close to a low-voltage sensor that you're handling, and putting into the ground, combined with an obvious lack of physical and electrical isolation...be extremely careful.

Comment: Thanks, @BrendanSimpson, I added the schematics for the board. Unfortunately, I don't have more info on the PSU, other than what's on the picture. If I don't recall wrong, it is a regular switching PSU extracted from a random device at home. Mains in Argentina is 220Vac. If isolated means using a transformer to isolate mains from Vdc, then it's isolated.

Comment: Thank you for the schematic. Are you _absolutely certain_ that your power supply is isolated? Not all switching regulators are isolated. Since you harvested it from something else, I assume you do not have any documentation on it. I suggest checking for continuity (or even a resistive path) from your low-voltage side ground to the ground connection at the mains input (with it unpowered, obviously). GFCI/RCD outlets can trip with uA of current flowing through the ground terminal.

Comment: > Are you absolutely certain that your power supply is isolated?
No, unfortunately, I cannot confirm that.  

> GFCI/RCD outlets can trip with uA of current flowing through the ground terminal.
Good to know. Will give it a try.

Comment: PSU looks isolated because of presence of optocoupler and blue capacitor. It can be bad quality or leaky, you may try to swap the fork in the line receptacle upside-down and see if it helps. Also, other devices connected to the same RCD can be also leaky and this PSU is a "last straw" that triggers it.

Comment: It looks like the PCB is not isolated on their sides, I'm assuming this is why the current is leaking to the ground?

https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2020/08/24/soil-moisture-sensors/